# Prove that $n^2= \theta(5n^2+n)$

Tags: asymptotics

i am trying to prove that $n^2= \theta(5n^2 + n)$
And i'm using this formula:

$c_1(5n^2 + n) ≤ n^2 ≤ c_2(5n^2 + n)$ $\forall n ≥ n_0$

Is it true? If it's true could you please help me for find the c1,c2 and n0. I found them but i'm not sure are they true or false. Thank you.

As for my attempt, in the comments it was pointed out that $n^2\leq 5n^2+n$ is already true for all positive $n$, that's why my mind confused about the $c_2$. I found the $c_1$ is $\frac{1}{5}$ and $n_0= 5$ but I'm not sure are they true or false

Comment: "*I found them but I'm not sure are they true or false*"  What did you find?  I will point out that we do not require that these values be strict and there are infinitely many equally correct answers that you could give.  A bit point of problems like this is to be creative.

Comment: As a hint, $n^2\leq 5n^2+n$ is already true for all positive $n$.  Meanwhile $5n^2+n\leq 6n^2$ is also true for all positive $n$.  Do you see why and how this can lead you to one of the many possible solutions?

Comment: Yes as you said n2≤5n2+n is already true for all positive n, that's why my mind confused about the c2. I found the c1 is 1/5 and n0= 5 but I'm not sure are they true or false.

Comment: $n^2 \leq \color{blue}{1}\cdot (5n^2+n)$...  As for $c_1$ being $\frac{1}{5}$, that is not small enough.  Notice that $\frac{1}{5}(5n^2+n) = n^2+\frac{n}{5}$ is always *greater* than $n^2$.

Comment: Oh you're right, so c1 might be 1/6 ? We are searching a upper bound for c1 right?  And could you please give me an idea about n0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One among many valid final answers (*and the easiest to see in my opinion*) is to try to use $n_0=1$ and choose the values of $c_1,c_2$ accordingly.

We notice that $n^2\leq 1\cdot (5n^2+n)$ is true for all $n$ so setting $c_2=1$ suffices.  This just follows from "if I add a positive number to another positive number then I make it bigger" as well as "if I multiply a positive number bigger than $1$ to another positive number then I make it bigger", properties that you should be well familiar with already.

Now, on the other side, we have that $5n^2+n \leq 5n^2+n^2 = 6n^2$ is true for all positive $n$ as well.  This, again following from the earlier mentioned properties.  By dividing both sides of this inequality by six, we arrive at $\frac{5}{6}(5n^2+n)\leq n^2$.

We have as a result, one of the many possible choices for $c_1,c_2,n_0$ as being $c_1=\frac{1}{6},c_2=1,n_0=1$ as we have that:

$$\frac{1}{6}(5n^2+n)\leq n^2\leq 1(5n^2+n)~~~~\forall n\geq 1$$

---

Now, as mentioned, you could have used many other choices for $c_1,c_2,n_0$.  The end result for this specific problem is that you could let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be any values such that $0<c_1<\frac{1}{5}$ and $c_2\geq\frac{1}{5}$ and then let $n_0$ be however big it needed to be in order to let that work.  $c_1$ being *equal* to $\frac{1}{5}$ is not small enough.  However, none of that actually matters.  All that was necessary for this problem was to find *any* example that works, and the one above does that just fine.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as you about the c2 after your comment, yes they are many other choices but we are looking for a upper bound for c1 and lower bound for c2 right? That's why 1/6 and 1 solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: We are *not* looking for upper and lower bounds.  If you are actually interested in upper and lower bounds that would be 1/5 in both cases.